# Find the roots of the simple equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

x^{2}= 0
What are the roots? are they in complex plane, but how?
Answer seems trivial in real numbers ain't it?
Does this evolve a new system like it was with iota?

Comment: $\Delta=$?? Do you know this?

Comment: del operator ?.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant :)

Comment: It may seem nonsense but my teacher called these numbers something else...

Answer (score 2):

The root is $0$, multiplicity two. It is a real root, but real numbers are also complex numbers.  Any real number $x$ can be expressed as $x + 0i$.

$$z = 0 + 0i = 0 \in \mathbb C$$

No need to evolve a new system to be able to express $0$.

Answer (score 1):

You should observe that $\mathbb{C}$ is a field. Hence, if $ab=0$ then either $a$ or $b$ is zero.

In other rings containing $\mathbb{R}$ you could have more solutions, but not in a field.